# What does the `shell:` prefix do in the Run dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shell, windows-11, run-dialog

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `shell:startup` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will bring up the Startup folder.

What does the `shell:` prefix do and what arguments does it accept?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog accepts commands, file paths, **or URLs** (URIs). The `shell:` prefix acts as a URL scheme, much like `http:` or `ftp:` or `mailto:`.

'Shell' is a traditional term for the OS component that handles the overall user interface (taskbars, program launching, file management) – in this case, Windows Explorer is the graphical "shell". The "Run" dialog is also part of Explorer.

So "shell:" addresses are URLs recognized by Windows Explorer itself to open various miscellaneous locations (similar to how web browsers might have "about:" or "chrome:").

It seems that the list of accepted "shell:" URLs is based on this registry key, specifically, the `Name` values of each of its subkeys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

For example, `shell:my video` will look up the registry key where `Name` = `My Video`, which nowadays points to the ~\Videos\ directory.